# How to strip first and last byte from binary data in Python

Tags: python, binary-data

I have a Python program that is receiving data from a UDP socket. Python is reading it as binary data.

Each datagram should start with the STX character (0x02) and end with the ETX character (0x03). I want my code to test the first and last character and, if they are correct, to strip them before passing the rest of the data out of my function to be further processed by the calling function.

I believe I can test the first character with `data[0]`.

How can I get the length of the data so as to test the last character?

How can I get a "substring" of the data?

I am tempted to decode it to a string, but suspect that involves extra overhead and anyway, as a Python novice, I have no idea how.

Comment: As I understand you can try `data[1:-1]`

Comment: len(s.encode('utf-8'))

Comment: In python, you can do indexing from start to end. So for example, data[-1] accesses the last entry in the list, data[-3] the third-to-last index, etc.

Comment: @Osadhi, please put that as an answer so I can accept it. Also please include Brimbo's comment on how to access the last byte. I inferred it from your comment, but it would be good for others in the future if you mentioned it explicitly. Thanks for you (very quick) help.

Comment: @AlastairG Did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the question you need to slice your data.
So you can slice from 2nd character by using `data[1:]` and up to last character but not including by using `data[:-1]`. 
As a combination of both, you can use

```
data[1:-1]
```

You can get length by using `len()` function.

```
len(data)
```

You can get the last byte by:

```
data[-1]
```